# Swift 5 Problems saving CoreData after swiping to delete

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm really new to Swift and Xcode and am trying to build an app for the group I play golf with.

I have a tableView that allows me to add new names to a list that is stored in CoreData.  The problem comes in when I try to swipe to delete names in the list.  Swiping brings up the DELETE button, when I press DELETE, the data is removed from the view but is isn't being saved.  When the app is closed and reopened, the deleted name is still there.

Here is the relevant code:(UPDATED TO INCLUDE ALL CODE AFTER CHANGES)

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  coreDataTest
//
//  Created by MyMac on 11/22/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 waltschroeder. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Set IBOutlet for Table View
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // Define variable for player names
    var players: [NSManagedObject] = []
    var container: NSPersistentContainer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        title = "Player Maintenance"
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "coreDataTest")

        container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unresolved error \(error)")
            }
        }

    }

    // Fetch data from CoreData
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //1
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        //2
        let fetchRequest =
            NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")

        //3
        do {players = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    // Add new player to CoreData
    @IBAction func addName(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Player",
                                      message: "Add Player",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) {
            [unowned self] action in

            guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
                let nameToSave = textField.text else {
                    return
            }

            self.save(name: nameToSave)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                         style: .cancel)

        alert.addTextField()

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }

    // Save entered data to CoreData
    func save(name: String) {

        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity =
            NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person",
                                       in: managedContext)!

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                     insertInto: managedContext)

        person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            players.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    // Delete player from CoreData

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            self.players.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            savePlayers()

        }

    }

    // Save Changes

    func savePlayers() {
        if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try container.viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("An error occurred while saving: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

}
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return players.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        -> UITableViewCell {

            let person = players[indexPath.row]
            let cell =
                tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",
                                              for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text =
                person.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
            return cell
    }
}
```

If more of the code is needed, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You never init

```
var container: NSPersistentContainer!
```

so replace

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: “coreDataTest”)
```

with

```
container = NSPersistentContainer(name: “coreDataTest”)
```

Comment: Okay - so no more error but when I delete the line items they are removed from the screen but not from CoreData.  I think I'm going start over from scratch.